# How search whitespaces on &lt; and &gt; on link without tag html <a href=""> </a>

Tags: regex, find, whitespace

simple find whitespaces `\s+` with regex: 
exemplo match: `&lt;https://reg exr.com/&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

```
([^"]*)\&[l]t;([^"]*)+\s+([^"]*)\&[g]t;([^"]*)
```